# What is the Marco glass wood fireplace fresh air vent lever closed position?

Tags: vent, fireplace

[image]What is the Marco glass wood fireplace fresh air vent lever closed position? Up, neutral, or down?

Comment: check the user manual

Comment: Down is a common position for closed, but not always.  For something like an air vent, can usually try in both positions to either look and see, or feel if the air flow changes.  Looking in the manual(maybe online) is good also.

Answer (score 2):

- Stick your head in the fireplace.
- Shine a flashlight up the chimney.
- Have a helper move the lever.
- You should have no problem seeing the damper move

  - When it's closed, you yell to your helper "It's closed!".
  - Make sure helper stops moving the lever at that point.

You can then look at the lever position and make a label indicating the closed position.

---

**Important Notes:**

1. Make sure there is no fire burning when you're doing this, you're not Harry Potter.
2. Eye protection is recommended as moving the damper will possibly dislodge crud that you don't want in your eyes.

   1. Consider a face shield, as you probably don't want to come out of the process looking like [Bert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Poppins_(film)#Cast)

Comment: While that is good advice for a normal fireplace chimney damper, this type of lever _(on the side of the firebox)_  is actually used for the inlet of combustion air. The chimney/flue damper is controlled a separate lever at the top.

Answer (score 2):

On Marco manufactured fireplaces:

- Lever up = outside air inlet OPEN
- Lever down = outside air inlet CLOSED

[image: Marco outside air control lever illustration]
*(Note: sometimes the ‘down’ position does not appear quite as shown in this illustration; regardless, the down-most position is still the ‘closed’ position)*

Background: This side lever, when present, is for introducing air from outside to help in combustion. While the fireplace is installed, the air inlet is generally not visible; it is located on the right side of the firebox, and is commonly connected either to a crawlspace or to an air vent on the outside wall of the home.

If there is no sign of outside air when the lever is up / OPEN, check the air inlet outside *(or in a crawlspace)* to make sure it is not obstructed.